# Multiple MySite hosts for multiple Web Applications

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service, 2016

I have searched the interwebz, but haven't found anything specific. Problems are either different or answers are 5 years old.

I've got a SharePoint 2016 on premise farm. 2 Web applications: companyA and companyB. Users need to be synchronized from 2 domains: companyADomain and companyBDomain.

I have set up 2 separate web applications to host My Sites A and B. Set up 2 UPS applications:
First one: synchronizes users from companyADomain, MySites are configured to redirect users to My Site A.
Second one: synchronizes users from companyBDomain, MySites are configured to redirect users to My Site B.

Let's say I have 2 test users. Test User A (from A domain) and Test User B (from B domain). UPS syncs users in a proper way - User A ends up in UPS A and User B ends up in UPS B.

The problem: on either of the web applications and by either of the users, when they click on "About Me" on the ribbon, they are both redirected to My Site A. Which is correct for User A, but I want user B to be redirected to My Site B.

Does anyone have any clues what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is user b also part of domain A? when it redirected to MySite A, did he get access denied or something else?

Comment: No, both test users are on separate domains. They don't get access denied, but instead they can open MySite and it show's a profile page `person.aspx`.

Comment: do you have trust between both domains? also check from central admin... web app A should have User Profile A in connected services and User Profile B is connected with Web APP B....only one Upa associated with each web application

Comment: There is trust between the domains. Waqas, I know that would sort out the issue, but I can't configure it like that. The requirement is that users from both domains should be able to browse both web applications, but should be redirected to their own MySite when they click on "Abou me". So I can't disable the connections.

Comment: then why you need two User Profile and MYsites....you can achieve with one UPA. OOTB user will access only their own mysite unless some one give the permissions to user on their mysite....Profile can be visited by anyone.

Comment: I would have done it differently but I kind of inherited this project and I can't spend a lot of time on it :)

Comment: Did you bind each web application to their respective User Profile Application? Also, did you set the permissions on each UPSA for each domain correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. What I have done eventually is configure one UPSA to sync all the users (A+B) and other UPSA to sync only users from domain B (not sure if needed at all). I used audiences to redirect users to their corresponding domains. Seems to work fine for now..